# Bi directionnal relation many-to-many (on same table) with sqlAlchemy, python and pydantic (fastapi)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pydantic, alembic

I wonder, if it's possible to have a many to many relation *on the same table* without extra table (with IDs) ?

I've basicly this one :

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, Table, text
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship
import uuid
from typing import List
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

association_table = Table(
    "association_table_user_to_prev_user", 
    Base.metadata,
    Column("user_id", Integer, ForeignKey("user.id")),
    Column("prev_user_id", Integer, ForeignKey("user.prev_user_id")))

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String)

    prev_user_id = mapped_column(ForeignKey('user.id'))
    prev_user: Mapped[List["User"]] = relationship(secondary=association_table, back_populates="prev_user")



user_a = User(username="Andrew")
print(f"user A={user_a}")
```

So, can  I have the same relation but, in "many to many" way ?. This, **without** an extra table ;  like : prev_table(id, prev_id)

Can I create an invisible association_table ?

Thanks a lot

F.

Comment: Why don't you like the solution with association table?

Comment: I don't really dislike this solution, but I have only one table related to this same table.
How can I do with one table with many to many relationship with herself ? Thanks

Comment: But you still need a place to store information about links between different rows of that table. IMO, association table is a good solution here

Comment: Can you give me an example please ?

Comment: I thought you want something like this (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/join_conditions.html#self-referential-many-to-many-relationship). But now I'm not sure I was right. Do you want to use the same attribute for both directions? Can you give an example of how you are going to use this model? I think the attribute name `prev_user` is confusing..

Comment: The example is not very clear. It's not based on "User", but "Package". So, the "prev_user", "prev package" reference an another record, late on date time.

Comment: So, if `prev_packages` are pointers to `packages` in the past, then back reference attribute should be named `next_packages`. e.g.: `current.prev_packages.append(previous)` and then `assert current in previous.next_packages`

Answer (score 0):

I try this, and it's seems good.

Another idea ?

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, Table, text
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
from pprint import pprint

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

package_to_prev = Table(
    "package_to_prev",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("current_package_id", Integer, ForeignKey("package.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("previous_package_id", Integer, ForeignKey("package.id"), primary_key=True),
)


class Package(Base):
    __tablename__ = "package"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    label = Column(String)
    prev_package = relationship(
        "Package",
        secondary=package_to_prev,
        primaryjoin=id == package_to_prev.c.previous_package_id,
        secondaryjoin=id == package_to_prev.c.previous_package_id,
        backref="previous_packages",
    )
    
event_1 = Package(id="10", label="current package")
pprint(f"event_1={event_1.id} // {event_1.label} // {event_1.prev_package}")

event_2 = Package(id="9", label="event_2 prev_package")
pprint(f"event_2={event_2.id} // {event_2.label} // {event_2.prev_package}")

event_1.prev_package.append(event_2)

event_3 = Package(id="8", label="event_3 prev_package")
pprint(f"event_3={event_3.id} // {event_3.label} // {event_3.prev_package}")
event_1.prev_package.append(event_3)

print()
pprint(f"event_1 with all previous packages={[(o.id, o.label, o.prev_package) for o in event_1.prev_package]}")
```